# How to log each instance of a Class into different files with Nlog?

Tags: c#, wpf, nlog

I have a project where I am testing eight pieces of the same equipment at the same time. I need to be able to write to a log for each piece of equipment. I also need to have another log file that has system log messages. In the past I have written my own logging but would like to try Nlog. I wrote a simple test to see if this would work and I am not having much success. What I would like to do is have each instance of `TempObject` log into its own file. Currently the following code logs into each of the log files:

*NLog.Config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logfile.txt" />
    <target name="myObj1" xsi:type="File" fileName="myObj1.txt" />
    <target name="myObj2" xsi:type="File" fileName="myObj2.txt" />
    <target name="myObj3" xsi:type="File" fileName="myObj3.txt" />
    <target name="myObj4" xsi:type="File" fileName="myObj4.txt" />
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj1" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj2" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj3" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj4" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  private TempObject myObj1 = new TempObject(1);
  private TempObject myObj2 = new TempObject(2);
  private TempObject myObj3 = new TempObject(3);
  private TempObject myObj4 = new TempObject(4);

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    logger.Info("this is the first log message");        
    myObj1.LogMessage();
    myObj2.LogMessage();
    myObj3.LogMessage();
    myObj4.LogMessage();
    SetUpDisplay();
  }
}
```

*TempObject.cs*

```
public class TempObject
{
  private int myUUT;

  private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public TempObject(int uutNumber)
  {
    myUUT = uutNumber;
  }

  public void LogMessage()
  {
    logger.Info("UUT" + myUUT);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify -  using the current code you have given, all instances log into the same logfile.

Comment: Currently for each instance of TempObject the call logger.Info("UUT" + myUUT); will log into each of the following log files: logfile, myObj1, myObj2, myObj3 myObj4.  I would like myObj1 instance of TempObject to log into myObj1 log file only, myObj2 instance  of TempObject to log into myObj2 log file only, myObj3 instance  of TempObject to log into myObj3 log file only, myObj4 instance  of TempObject to log into myObj4 log file only.

Comment: hmm. as Nlog correctly only sets the filename in the config, this may be tedious. you could use the ReconfigExistingLoggers of Nlog, after changing the target, but this you have to call each time you have log statement (but this is manipulating a config file at runtime for wrong reasons)

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the following in the TempObject and it works.

```
public class TempObject
{
  private int myUUT;

  private Logger myLogger;

  public TempObject(int uutNumber)
  {
    myUUT = uutNumber;
    string logString = "myObj" + myUUT;
    myLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(logString);
  }

  public void LogMessage(string msg)
  {
    myLogger.Info("UUT" + myUUT+ "|" + msg);
  }
}
```

and the rules section of the config file to:

```
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  <logger name="myObj1" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj1" />
  <logger name="myObj2" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj2" />
  <logger name="myObj3" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj3" />
  <logger name="myObj4" minlevel="Info" writeTo="myObj4" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```